# Load static HTML file and split into array by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on this for days and I get close but not all the way.  Most of the SO answers I have found, help me get the file contents loaded into a div or a variable but it doesn't let me then do querySelectorAll on it.  So, what I need to do is load the file and then break it up into an array based on a class.  Without further ado, the code:

content.txt:

```
<h3 class="chapter">Chapter 1</h3>
<p>Lorem</p>
<h3 class="chapter">Chapter 2</h3>
<p>Lorem</p>
```

Loading JS:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "content/content.txt",
      cache: false,
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function(html){          
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = html;
        var chapters = div.querySelectorAll('chapter');
        alert(chapters.length);

      }
    });
```

Expected Result:

```
['<h3 class="chapter">Chapter 1</h3><p>Lorem</p>',
  '<h3 class="chapter">Chapter 2</h3><p>Lorem</p>']
```

So this loads the file (confirmed) and I have the html in a variable.  I try loading it into a dynamic DIV in the DOM to do a `querySelectorAll` but all it returns is {}.  If I dump the `innerHTML` all of my content is there.

I know I am mixing vanilla JS with jQuery, but I am unsure of the proper jQuery way to go about this.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry that was a bad copy paste.  I have edited the post to reflect the appropriate code.

Comment: Then it seems you just forgot a dot in front of `chapter`.

Comment: OMG!  I am a dummy.  Thats working now.  Seriously, 2 days wasted on trying all sorts of different options from XHR to load and on and on.  Thank you!

Comment: Do you create "content.txt"? if you do, you should use proper html... use chapter as a class or name, so you can do something like `$(html).each(".chapter", function(){...});` otherwise you could check if by chance this works: `$(html).each("h3",function(){ if(attr(align)=="chapter"){...}});`

Comment: It will be user created in a static file.  The requirement is they use the chapter class.  It could be any sort of tag which is why we are using the class attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector `chapter` will match all your `<chapter>` elements. There is no such element in HTML and there is no such element in your text file. That is why nothing matches.

`align="chapter"` is invalid HTML. `chapter` is not a valid value for the `align` attribute, which is obsolete anyway.

Start by writing sensible HTML. Use a class to distinguish between types of div elements.

```
<div class="chapter">
```

For that matter, consider using the `<section>` element instead.

Then use a class selector (instead of a type selector):

```
div.querySelectorAll('.chapter');
```

Comment: I had a bad copy/paste & edit to SO.  Align was supposed to be class.  As @Gothdo stated above, I simply forgot the period for the class.  Your final code statement is correct.  Thanks!